# How to find max value by date (timestamp) by cell_id

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to find the max value of a column, within a date range (by day), within the context of a third column. I'm an SQL newbie, so go easy.

Basically - **max value, by day, by cell_id**.

Each "Weather_Cell_ID" has data for each hour, for each day. Sample below.

Notice: The are multiple dates

My current PostgreSQL table looks roughly like:

```
+-----------------+------------------+------------+
| Weather_Cell_ID |      Dates       | Wind_Speed |
+-----------------+------------------+------------+
|            0001 | 2019-01-21 01:00 | 4.6        |
|            0001 | 2019-01-21 02:00 | 2.4        |
|            0001 | 2019-01-21 04:00 | 8.5        |
|            0001 | 2019-01-22 10:00 | 6.2        |
|            0001 | 2019-01-21 14:00 | 14.8       |
|            0002 | 2019-01-21 01:00 | 3.5        |
|            0002 | 2019-01-21 05:00 | 9.6        |
|            0002 | 2019-01-22 06:00 | 4.8        |
|            0002 | 2019-01-21 16:00 | 12.2       |
|            0002 | 2019-01-21 08:00 | 4.6        |
|            0003 | 2019-01-21 03:00 | 4.9        |
+-----------------+------------------+------------+
```

My current code looks like:

```
select weather_cell_id, 
    date_trunc('day', dates) as dates, 
    max(windspeed) as maxwindspeed
from view_6day_mat
GROUP BY weather_cell_id, view_6day_mat.dates
order by weather_cell_id
```

This however produces basically the same table with the HH:MI set to 00:00.

What I'm hoping to see as an output is:

```
+-----------------+------------+------------+
| Weather_Cell_ID |   Dates    | Wind_Speed |
+-----------------+------------+------------+
|            0001 | 2019-01-21 | 14.8       |
|            0001 | 2019-01-22 | 6.2        |
|            0002 | 2019-01-21 | 12.2       |
|            0002 | 2019-01-22 | 4.8        |
|            0003 | 2019-01-21 | 4.9        |
+-----------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    weather_cell_id, 
    dates::date as dates_date, 
    max(windspeed) as maxwindspeed
from view_6day_mat
GROUP BY weather_cell_id, dates_date
order by weather_cell_id
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you. I'll mark it as correct.

Are you able to explain why it works / what it's doing? What is `dates::date as dates_date' doing?

Comment: @anakaine In PostgreSQL `<value>::<type>` converts value of one type to another one (if converting is possible). It is same to SQL standard `cast(<value> as <type>)` In this particular case `dates::date` converts value of `timestamp` type to `date` type. In other words it removes the `time` and leaves only `date` part. For example: `select current_timestamp, current_timestamp::date, cast(current_timestamp as date);` Then you can group your data not only by table's columns but also by expressions in the `select` clause.